# How do I use the github PUT call from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, git, github

From the github api:

`PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`

I want to be able to put/update a file directly from a web application

```
function httpPUT(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

}
```

I'm not sure how to exactly call it from javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/some_name/some_app/issues/23?access_token=some_number',
  type: 'PATCH',
  data: '{"state": "closed" }',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(result) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  }
});
```

**I am warning you though, it is a bad idea to share your token on the client side!**

Comment: What would be the "safe" way to do this?

Comment: What is the `some_name,some_app` in this case? and what about the `23?`